# Blender support for Android

Tags: blender-game-engine

I want to design 3D games for my android smart phone. Though I that two powerful game development software like Blender (under Linux) supports 3D game development. My question is:

How can a game developed under Blender can be exported to Android devices?

Comment: You should probably ask one thing at a time. Also please note [how to get started](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or "which technology one should use" question types are out of scope of this site. On these kinds topic you are probably better trying some discuss oriented sites.

Answer (score 2):

Blender and it's game engine don't directly support android.

Third party apps like Unity can import model and animation data created in blender, possible export to other formats may be required.

A more low level approach is gamekit. You can also code a game from scratch like any android app and have it read data from a blend file or other exported file format.